# Is this the correct usage of a view in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I have two tables. One stores locations and another stores different ratings for those locations (where ratings can come from different users, so one location can have many ratings). I'd like a way to display the location name next to it's average ratings. I believe I need to use a view to create this. Here are my tables:

- `locations` has a `name` property and an `id` property which is a foreign key to my `ratings` table `location_id`.
- `ratings` has a `location_id` property, a `user_id` property and properties to hold a rating for `eating`, `reading`, `child_friendly`, `pet_friendly` and `accessible`.

This is the view I've created:

```
CREATE VIEW v_location_averages AS
SELECT
    r.location_id,
    t.name,
    t.eating,
    t.reading,
    t.child_friendly,
    t.pet_friendly,
    t.accessible,
    (COALESCE(t.eating, 0) + COALESCE(t.reading, 0) + COALESCE(t.child_friendly, 0) + COALESCE(t.pet_friendly, 0) + COALESCE(t.accessible, 0)) / num_nonnulls(t.eating, t.reading, t.child_friendly, t.pet_friendly, t.accessible) AS "overall_rating"
FROM (
    SELECT 
        locations.name,
        location_id, 
        AVG(eating) AS "eating",
        AVG(reading) AS "reading",
        AVG(child_friendly) AS "child_friendly",
        AVG(pet_friendly) AS "pet_friendly",
        AVG(accessible) AS "accessible",
    FROM ratings 
    INNER JOIN locations on ratings.location_id = locations.id
    GROUP BY location_id, locations.name
) t
JOIN ratings r ON r.location_id = t.location_id
GROUP BY r.location_id, t.name, t.eating, t.reading, t.child_friendly, t.pet_friendly, t.accessible;
```

Is this the correct way to achieve what I want, and is this the best way to create that view? (It definitely works, but is it correct?)

Comment: Yes, it's absolutely OK to use a view here. In fact a lot better than all those countless requests here asking to materialize such aggregations in (parent) tables.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Is that an efficient way to work out the averages too please? As presumably it calculates them every time someone selects from the view?

Comment: This seems more a question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please ask a new question in a new post. Re this being correct: Please give a [mre]. That includes a clear specification & DDL. Is "display the location name next to its average ratings" enough for someone to come back with code doing what you want? (Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values.) Why is this maybe not correct? PS Please don't cross post to multiple sites.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @philipxy - I'll do that in future (as this one's already been answered)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really good practice to use views, but in your case view can be more simple:

```
CREATE VIEW v_location_averages AS
SELECT
    t.location_id,
    l.name,
    t.eating,
    t.reading,
    t.child_friendly,
    t.pet_friendly,
    t.accessible,
    (COALESCE(t.eating, 0) + COALESCE(t.reading, 0) + COALESCE(t.child_friendly, 0) + COALESCE(t.pet_friendly, 0) + COALESCE(t.accessible, 0)) / num_nonnulls(t.eating, t.reading, t.child_friendly, t.pet_friendly, t.accessible) AS "overall_rating"
FROM (
    SELECT 
        location_id, 
        AVG(eating) AS "eating",
        AVG(reading) AS "reading",
        AVG(child_friendly) AS "child_friendly",
        AVG(pet_friendly) AS "pet_friendly",
        AVG(accessible) AS "accessible",
    FROM ratings 
    GROUP BY location_id
) t 
INNER JOIN locations l on t.location_id = l.id;
```